# No receiver allowed to receive com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND at Gcm.Client.GcmClient.CheckManifest - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using GCM to receive push notification in Android. I have below code in Android main activity, which is dependent on Xamarin.Forms project

```
 try
           {
               //Check to see that GCM is supported and that the manifest has the correct information
               GcmClient.CheckDevice(this);
               GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);

               var registrationId = GcmClient.GetRegistrationId(this);
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registrationId))
               {
                   GcmClient.Register(this, GcmBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS);
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {

           }
```

While executing check manifest its throwing below exception:

```
No receiver allowed to receive com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND
  at Gcm.Client.GcmClient.CheckManifest
```

But I have added necessary permission in manifest, below is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <permission android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <application android:label="Mobile.Droid" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></application>
```

I am having same manifest file in one of my Xamarin.Android project, where its successfully registered with GCM, why here its throwing exception?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is because you don't set the permission of:

> *com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND*

Try to set the permissions in your custom BroadcastReceiver class like this:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" }, Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" }, Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY" }, Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
public class MyGCMBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    const string TAG = "PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver";
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        MyIntentService.RunIntentInService(context, intent);
        SetResult(Result.Ok, null, null);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps